# Calculate move by one pixel in the direction on specific point

Tags: python, pygame

I would like to move my image by one pixel in the direction on specific point. Right now I have:
My image cords:

```
position.x
position.y
```

Coordinates of the point where I want to move:

```
dest.x
dest.y
```

And the angle at which I must move to reach the designated place:

```
angle
```

How should you calculate for each step add / subtract 1 for x and y?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the angle is in radians, use trigonometry:

```py
import math

x += math.cos(angle) * amount_to_move
y += math.sin(angle) * amount_to_move
```

Comment: this will not (directly) achieve a single pixel movement

Comment: @Alnitak you can't move exactly one pixel at an angle on a discrete grid

Comment: sure you can - you just either move one pixel in X or in Y (see Bresenham's Line Drawing algorithm, as mentioned in the other answer).   The end result is the same.

Comment: @Alnitak oh I see

Answer (score 3):

If you want to move only in increments of 1 pixel in x or y at a time, it sounds like the coordinates you want correspond with the pixels on a straight line from source to destination. A common algorithm for drawing a pixellated straight line is the Bresenham algorithm:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm

So instead of drawing pixels, you could use the coordinates to position your image.

Comment: This is exactly what I was going to suggest.   It also has the advantage of only using integer math, and requires no trigonometry.